# Hierarchy in Fields pane in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I apologize if this is a 'starter' question but i have not been able to find any answers in tutorials.

This started when i accidentally let go of a entry in the fields pane in Power BI. The entries turned into a parent-child relationship ( please see image ), but i can't find any such relationship in query editor or relationship manager.

Power BI fields Pane

[image]

May i know what is this and how do i get rid of it?

Answer (score 7):

You have inadvertently created a custom hierarchy.

Your original fields still exist, so you just need to delete the hierarchy. To do that, right-click the hierarchy top level and select "Delete" from the context menu.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! They really should be more descriptive. When you press Delete, you really don't know what would happen, so you don't 'dare' to press it. And it doesn't make sense, to be honest. They should call it ' un-parent hierarchy' or 'collapse hierarchy'. Thanks very much!

Comment: If that answered your question please accept the answer as described in the [Tour].